# Vector subspaces of continuous functions

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $V = C^0 [a, b]$ be the set of all real-valued continuous functions on the domain $[a, b]$. Which of the following subsets $W_1,W_2$ are subspaces of $V$?

$W_1 =\{f \in C^0 [a, b] : |f(x)| \le M\,\, \text{for some}\,\, M \in R^+\}$, the set of bounded continuous functions on $[a, b]$

$W_2 = \{f \in C^0 [a, b] : f(-x) = f(x)\,\, \text{for all}\,\, x\}$, the set of even continuous functions on $[a, b]$

Okay, I know to show that $W$ is a subspace of $V$:

a. $W$ is non-empty.

b. if $x_1, x_2 \in W$ then $x_1 + x_2 \in W$

c. for $k \in R, kx_1 \in W$

Comment: Do you know the list of things that a subspace must satisfy?

Comment: yes I do, 



I'm just not sure how to go about showing it.

Comment: Well, since you know what you have to show, why not make a start on showing it, and we'll help you when you get stuck. Start by writing out what it is that you have to do to show something is a subspace.

Comment: OK, good start. Now: can you show $W_1$ is non-empty?

Comment: well my attempt

for $W_1$ is non-empty

$f(x)= 0$

$|0| \le M$

$0 \le M$

since $M \in R^+$, $W_1$ is non-empty?

Comment: Good! Now, can you show that if $f$ and $g$ are in $W_1$, then so is $f+g$? By the way, if you want to be sure I see a comment of yours, you have to put @Gerry in it (but of course others are welcome to jump in here and to help out).

Comment: The question is ill posed. What are the unbounded continuous functions on $[a,b]$? And what's the meaning of “$f(-x)=f(x)$ for all $x$” if $[a,b]=[1,2]$?

Comment: @egreg that's the question in its entirety..

Comment: @GerryMyerson
i thought about it and came up with this instead.
$f, g \in W_1$ then $f + g  \in W_1$

$|f + g| \le M$

$f+g \le M \notin W_1$

and therefore $W_1$is not closed under addition?

Comment: To show it's not closed under addition, you would want to find $f$ and $g$ in $W_1$ such that $f+g$ is not in $W_1$. Do you have such an example? Notice that the definition of $W_1$ allows you to use different values of $M$ for different functions.

Comment: not sure how to approach showing whether it is  closed under addition or not actually..dont quite know where to start.@GerryMyerson

Comment: You start by assuming $f$ and $g$ are in $W_1$, and letting $h=f+g$. Since $f$ is in $W_1$, you know $f$ is continuous, and $|f|\le M$ for some real $M$. Since $g$ is in $W_1$, you know $g$ is continuous, and $|g|\le N$ for some real $N$. You want to prove that $h$ is in $W_1$, so you want to prove that $h$ is continuous and that $|h|\le P$ for some real $P$. So: how do you prove that if $f$ and $g$ are continuous then so is $h=f+g$? how do you prove that if $|f|\le M$ and $|g|\le N$ then $|h|=|f+g|\le P$ for some $P$?

Comment: well the only thing I can come up with to prove that if $f$ and $g$ are continuous then $h = f + g$ is continuous..is:

if $f$ and $g$ are continuous at $a$, then $f + g$ are continuous at $a$

$\lim_{x\to a} |f(x)| = |f(a)| = f(a)$ and $\lim_{x\to a} |g(x)| = |g(a)| = g(a)$

$\lim_{x\to a} {|f + g}| = (\lim_{x\to a} |f(x)|) + (\lim_{x\to a} |g(x)|) = |f(a)| + |g(a)| = f(a) + g(a)$, so $f + g$ is continuous at a. 

then let $h = f + g$ and therefore $h$ would be continuous. @GerryMyerson

Comment: for the second  part, my approach:

if $|f| \le M$ and $|g| \le N$
then $|h| = |f + g| \le M + N \in R^+$

let $P = M+ N$ and therefore $|h| \le |f + g| \le P \in R^+$

Comment: above would mean that $f + g \in W_1$ 

similarly 

for $k \in R$ 

$k\lim_{x\to a} |f(x)| = k \cdot |f(a)| = k \cdot f(a)$ is continuous at a.

thus $k \cdot f \le k \cdot M \in W_1$

therefore by subspace test $W_1$ is a subspace of $V$...@GerryMyerson

Comment: Looks good (except you don't want the absolute value signs in the parts about limits and continuity; $f$ continuous at $a$ means $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)$.

Comment: yay, and thank you very, very much @GerryMyerson. I'll attempt $W_2$ now.

Comment: @GerryMyerson 
$W_2$ is non-empty
 
$f(x) = 0$

$f(-0) = f(0)$
the condition holds, thus $W_2$ is non-empty. 

$f(x), g(x) \in W_2$

they are continuous and $f(-x) = f(x), g(-x) = g(x)$ for all x

this result means that $f$ and $g$ are even functions

$(f + g)(-x) = f(-x) + g(-x) = f(x) + g(x) = (f + g)(x)$ for all x 

hence, $f + g$ is also even. therefore $f + g \in W_2$

for $k \in R$, 

$(kf)(-x) = kf(-x) = k(f(-x)) = k(f(x)) = kf(x)$ for all x

hence $kf$ is even. therefore, $kf \in W_2$

Comment: Looks good. Now you can post it as an answer. Then after a while you can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

## $W_1 =\{f \in C^0 [a, b] : |f(x)| \le M\,\, \text{for some}\,\, M \in R^+\}$, the set of bounded continuous functions on $[a, b]$

### a. $W_1$ is non- empty.

$f(x) = 0$

$|0| \le M$

$0 \le M$

since $M \in R^+$ then $W_1$ is non-empty.

### b. if $x_1, x_2 \in W_1$ then $x_1 + x_2 \in W_1$

$f(x), g(x) \in W_1$

$f(x), g(x)$ are continuous and $|f(x)| \le M, |g(x)| \le N$

show that $h(x)  \in W_1$ is such that $h(x)$ is continuous and $|h(x)| \le P$ for some $P \in R^+$

if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are continuous at a, then $f(x) + g(x)$ are continuous at a.

$\lim{x\to_a} f(x) = f(a)$ and $\lim{x\to_a} g(x) = g(a)$

$\lim{x\to_a} f(x) + g(x) = \lim{x\to_a} f(x) + \lim{x\to_a} g(x) = f(a) + g(a)$, so $f(x) + g(x)$ is continuous.

let $h(x) = f(x) + g(x)$ and therefore $h(x)$ would be continuous.

if $|f(x)| \le M, |g(x)| \le N$ then $h(x) = |f(x) + g(x)| \le M + N \in R^+$

let $P = M + N$, therefore $|h(x)| = |f(x) + g(x)| \le P \in R^+$

since $h(x)$ is continuous and for some $P \in R^+ |h(x)| \le P, h(x) \in W_1$ implies $f(x) + g(x) \in W_1$

### c. for $k \in R, kx_1 \in W_1$

similarly for $k \in R$

$k \cdot \lim{x\to_a} f(x) = k \cdot f(a)$, is continuous at a.

thus, $k \cdot f(x) \le k \cdot M \in W_1$

by subspace test, $W_1$ is a subspace of $V$

## $W_2 = \{f \in C^0 [a, b] : f(-x) = f(x)\,\, \text{for all}\,\, x\}$, the set of even continuous functions on $[a, b]$

### a. $W_2$ is non-empty

$f(x) = 0$

$f(-0) = f(0)$
the condition holds, thus $W_2$ is non-empty.

### b. if $x_1, x_2 \in W_2$ then $x_1 + x_2 \in W_2$

$f(x), g(x) \in W_2$

they are continuous and $f(-x) = f(x), g(-x) = g(x)$ for all x

this result means that $f$ and $g$ are even functions

$(f + g)(-x) = f(-x) + g(-x) = f(x) + g(x) = (f + g)(x)$ for all x

hence, $f + g$ is also even. therefore $f + g \in W_2$

### c. for $k \in R, kx_1 \in W_2$

for $k \in R$,

$(kf)(-x) = kf(-x) = k(f(-x)) = k(f(x)) = kf(x)$ for all x

hence $kf$ is even. therefore, $kf \in W_2$